# r programming - setting subset column data to lowercase

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a relatively "simple" request but so far I am failing. I have a data frame with a column that has upper case, i wish to convert to lower case so I can merge another data frame on the same key.

I can use tolower() to create another data frame with old and new and do a merge to the new data frame but I don't wish to use artificial joins and have extra columns that aren't really required.

I am sure I can use lapply but I haven't been able to 'update' the actual data frame.

He is a sample data frame df...

```
V1, V2
2015-11-19, ABC 
2015-11-19, DEF
2015-11-19, GHI
2015-11-19, JKL
```

I would like to update the df to...

```
V1, V2
2015-11-19, abc 
2015-11-19, def
2015-11-19, ghi
2015-11-19, jkl
```

Comment: Thanks, I previously tried that but it doesn't actually update the df. I also tried to put it in the subset (df, select = tolower(df$V2)) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: or: `df=within(df,V2<-tolower(V2))`

Comment: you have to assign it back to the `V2` column again: `df$V2 <- tolower(df$V2)`

Comment: Thanks. This df=within(df,V2<-tolower(V2)) worked perfectly!